# How to get multiple value from text box upon clicking on the add more button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to retrieve multiple values from text box when clicking on an add more button.

The add more button creates a new row for the user and has a count which is incremented every time a user creates a new text box.

The problem I am facing is how to retrieve multiple rows' values.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$custom=$_POST['custom_tr'];
  if (!empty($_POST['custom_tr'])) {
        $count =1;
  foreach ($custom as $key) {
    $col_name_ = 'col_name_'+$count;
    $col_formula = 'col_formula_'+$count;
   $get3=$_POST['col_name_'];
   $get4=$_POST['col_formula'];
    }
     $count++;
}
}
```

> The form and table used in this:

```
    <form id="id_form" action="#" method="post">
    <table id='tbl' cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="sortable" border="1">
      <tr><td> <input type='button' class='add-row' value='Add Row'>
      <button type='button' class='delete-row'>Delete Row</button> 
      <input type = 'submit' value = 'submit' name = 'submit' </td></tr>
```

> The add button has been implemented using jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {


var count=1;

   $(".add-row").click(function(){ 
    var markup = "<tr class='add_tr'><td><input type='checkbox' name='custom_tr[]' value='' ></td><td align='center'><input type='text' name='col_name_" + count + "' value='' class='own_col_name' placeholder='Type your new column here' ><br></td><td><input type='text' name='col_formula_" + count + "' class='own_col_formula' placeholder='Own formula'><br></td></tr>";
    $("#tbl tbody").append(markup);
count++;
    });
  });
```

I want to get the values of the different additional rows being added by the user.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: save it as an array.. `col_name[]` etc -

Comment: The question contains a malformed `input` tag.

Comment: `</td>` is an invalid closing markup for INPUT